# Why and where to use WCF

Tags: .net, c, wcf

I am new to WCF,can anybody help me to know Why and where to use WCF.

Recently I faced an Interview and the questions I faced was

What is the advantages of WCF and Why should we use it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain you problem with more clarity. Have a look on [How to ask on Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADVANTAGES OF USING WCF

- WCF unifies Web Services, .NET Remoting, and Enterprise Services stacks under one roof.
- In WCF configuration drives protocol choices, messaging formats, process allocation, etc.
- WCF services are loosely coupled, meaning that a WCF service is not bound to a particular protocol, encoding format, or hosting environment. Everything is configurable.